# Mapping of HttpStatusCode to Error Description

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

As all know, IIS render a yellow page as well as have `Http status code`, `Status description` and `Error description`.

e.g.

```
HTTP Error 500 - Internal Server Error
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

- `500`, is `Http status code`
- `Internal Server Error`, is `Status description`
- `The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred`, is `Error description`

When I have a Status code, I can get `Status description` by code `HttpWorkerRequest.GetStatusDescription(statusCode)`

**Question**, How can I get the `Error description` string of the Status code without any additional mapping resource. In other words, I want a bit of code can access the build-in Resources Table of IIS or Asp.net.